# Why does sed act differently depending on the output file?

Tags: linux, sed, pipe

If I run:

```sh
cat messages.txt | sed -e 's/a/a/g' > messages.txt
```

on one large file (2500+ lines) I find that the resulting file will only have about 900 lines after the command in cygwin and will have no lines in gentoo. However if I run

```sh
cat messages.txt | sed -e 's/a/a/g' > other_messages.txt
```

it retains all the lines as it should.

My question is why and is there any way to do it other than

```sh
cat messages.txt | sed -e 's/a/a/g' > other_messages.txt
rm messages.txt
mv other_messages.txt messages.txt
```

Comment: For the curious, the reason the former doesn't work is sed reads files a block at a time. It reads in the first block, processes it, and writes it to standard out. Before it can read the next block, your shell takes the first block of output from sed and inserts it into the output file -- if that's the same as the input file, the shell has just overwritten it. When sed goes to read the next block, it no longer exists, so it stops

Comment: It seems that Michael was writing his comment when I was writing my additional answer.  So many fast typers.

Comment: @Michael: Actually I believe the output file gets truncated before anything else happens.

Comment: @Dennis When it gets opened it probably does, but I think the shell waits to open it; otherwise you'd never get any input in sed, and I've seen the behavior the OP describes where part of the file is there and then it cuts off

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why don't you just write

```
sed -i -e 's/a/a/g' messages.txt
```

the -i means "in place"

Comment: Warning: not all variants of `sed` implement this option.

Answer (score 11):

[fschmitt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/why-does-sed-act-differently-depending-on-the-output-file/2760#2760) is the best when using sed;  however, in a more general sense this anti-pattern:

```
cat infile | filter > infile
```

is likely to cause you a good number of problems.  For instance if I have a file called `infile` that looks like this:

```
Hello
World
```

and run this command:

```
cat infile | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

I get

```
hello
world
```

But if I run `cat infile | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" > infile` I will get an empty file. Why?

Well, when you use the output redirection operator `>` you are saying "Put my standard output into this file, and if that file exists overwrite it."  Now you may think that this should work since your filter will return all the lines of the original file.  However, what often ends up happening is that the shell will clobber your file before any lines are read.  Then, your filter command will go to read lines from an empty file, find none, and thus return none.  In some places you might get "lucky" enough to have some lines read before the file gets clobber, but it is best to just avoid this pattern altogether.

To get around this particular issue you have a few options.  One is to simply do something like:

```
cat infile | filter > tmpfile; mv tmpfile infile
```

If you need to be sure that your temp file won't clobber some other file or have other nasty things happen to it, you should look into `mktemp`. (see `man mktemp` and `info coreutils mktemp`)

Another option is to use `sponge` from [moreutils](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/moreutils/).

Also, many of these examples are examples of [useless uses of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Answer (score 2):

Yet another (portable) way to edit a file in-place is to use `ed`.

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s messages.txt
H
,g/a/s//b/g
wq
EOF


# ... or read the file contents into a variable, modify it and write it back to file
file_contents="$(cat messages.txt)"
printf '%s' "$file_contents" | sed -e 's/a/b/g' > messages.txt


# ... and, if you want to play around with a file descriptor hack, ...
# (As long as there's a fd associated with a file, the file can be accessed via the fd.) 

exec 3<messages.txt  # open file on fd 3 for reading
rm -f messages.txt
sed -e 's/a/b/g' <&3 > messages.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/OLD/NEW/g|x' messages.txt
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` global replace
4. `x` save and close