# In-place substitution for lines matching some pattern in a given set of files

Tags: shell, grep, regular-expression

Following on from my previous question:

> [Remove slashes/parent paths from filenames inside CSS and Javascript content](/questions/16541/)

I arrived at the following command which replaces any filenames in these files with just the basename:

```
grep -o -h -E '[A-Za-z0-9:./_-]+\.(png|jpg|gif|tif|css)' |\
  sed "s:[a-zA-z0-9]*/::" `find . -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js'`
```

How do I save the output of this command back to the source file for each file processed?

Comment: The `-i` option in sed will make the changes to your files. Can you try modifying your bash line to use this?

Comment: @Manny - I get sed: 1: "./example.com-saved/example ...": invalid command code .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does sed act differently depending on the output file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/why-does-sed-act-differently-depending-on-the-output-file)

Answer (score 1):

Late answer to an old question, but I think this is the answer the OP was looking for:

```
SEDCMD="/[A-Za-z0-9:./_-]+\.(png|jpg|gif|tif|css)/ s:[a-zA-z0-9]*/::"
find . -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js' -exec sed -i "$SEDCMD" '{}' ';'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a loop, like:

```
find . -name '*.css' -or -name '*.js' | while read filename; do
  : $filename is the original file name
done
```