# Why `paste file1 file2 > file1` will replace content of file 1 with that of file2?

Tags: text-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does sed act differently depending on the output file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/why-does-sed-act-differently-depending-on-the-output-file)

I wonder why this command will simply replace the content of file1 with the content of file2, instead of the combination the original content of the two files?

```
paste file1 file2 > file1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The redirection clobbers `file1`. This is why we redirect to a different filename and rename after.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain what "the redirection clobbers file1" mean?